# THREE js - How would create a ground reflection to reflect meshes only

Tags: three.js

I would like to create a reflection on the ground. The reflection would only have the meshes not decorative data such as world origin.

I have tried to use THREE.Reflector but its reflects everything on the scene.[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple modification of `Reflector`. The idea is to use [THREE.Layers](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Layers) in order to control which objects are visible on the reflective surface.

1. `Reflector` has an internal virtual camera for rendering. Enable layer 1 and disable layer 0 of this camera.

   ```
   virtualCamera.layers.disable( 0 );
   virtualCamera.layers.enable( 1) ;
   ```
2. Define in your scene which objects should be visible for the mirror by enabling the respective layer (layer 0 is enabled by default).

   ```
   object.layers.enable( 1 );
   ```

Full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/9537/

Comment: Alright, I found the problem. There was a light on the scene and I have to enable the layers on light also. Thganks for your quick answer it really saved my day.

Comment: hi, excellent example.. is it possible to fade the reflection?

Comment: Yes, but the class does not allow you to configure this. Hence, you need to write custom shader code.